# Rails update_attributes using has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, update-attributes

I am working in a project where users can either have `admin: true / false`. The application will only let admin users login in to the system, the other users are just clients whose settings only admins can edit. This is some sort of commerce application.(**Rails 3.2.13**)

I would like to keep both concepts in the same table since in the future there will possibly be the option of logging in for non-admin users and interact with their profiles, so all the logic will be already implemented.

I've got this `User` resource:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20131204200554) do

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "surname"
    t.boolean  "admin"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "auth_token"
  end

end
```

This is the  user model:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_secure_password
    attr_accessible :name, :surname,:email, :password, :password_confirmation

    validates :name, presence:true, length: { maximum:50}
    validates :first_surname, presence:true, length: { maximum:50}
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX= /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i 
    validates :email, presence: true,format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive:false}
    validates :password, length:{minimum:6}
    validates :password_confirmation, presence:true
    before_save{ self.email.downcase! }
    before_save :generate_auth_token
    private
    def generate_auth_token
        self.auth_token=SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
end
```

And I am trying to implement the functionality of `User` editing, however I only want to allow the editing of `name`, `surname` and `email`. Hence, I present only those fields in the form:

```rb
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name,"Name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.label :surname,"Surname" %>
  <%= f.text_field :surname %>
  <%= f.label :email,"Email" %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <%= f.submit "Save" %>
```

I am trying to accomplish the goal with this code:

```rb
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    # Handle a successful update.
    flash[:success]="User updated successfully"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    flash[:danger]="Error updating user"
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

My problem is that when trying to `update_attributes` I get *not* unexpectedly an error validating `password/password_confirmation`, but since I'm using `has_secure_password`, these fields do not exist in the database, only `password_digest`. I am thinking about the best option to accomplish all this:

1. Update `@user` object with new field values.
2. Reflect this change in `User` table.
3. Run the validations, i.e. email validation.

While using `has_secure_password`. These are the options so far:

1. Use of `update_attribute`(best so far).
    
   **1.1 Pro**: updates the `User` table
   **1.2 Con**: I have to `update_attribute(field1)` for each of the fields, so more lines of code
   **1.3 Con**: Apparently this method no longer exists in Rails 4, problem in case an upgrade is desirable in the future.
   **1.4 Con**: No validations
2. Use of `@user.attributes=params[:user]` in the controller method
   **2.1 Pro**: Updates multiple fields at once.
   **2.2 Con**: Does not update the `User` table.
3. User of `update_attributes`
   **3.1 Pro**: Both multiple fields and table update
   **3.2 Con**: Not working ( duh!)

Suggestions?

Comment: I just wanted to point out that `update_attribute` does exist in Rails 4. `update_attribute(:field, 'value')`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you want to validate the presence of password on create only (also notice more concise way to validate password confirmation):

```
validates :password, length:{minimum:6}, confirmation: true, on: :create
```

You can then use `update_attributes`

You may want to restrict what params can be submitted by using strong params:

- Gem: https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters
- also included in Rails 4 http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: oh, of course! That makes a lot of sense, thank you. I also appreciate the `confirmation: true` tip, much more compact. With regard to the Strong params, I would use a more *by-hand* version, i.e. `params[:user].slice(:name,:email)`. But your suggestion looks much more embedded and possibly convenient in some cases.

Comment: If you wanted to take a more granular approach, I would suggest `params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)` as it is in the Rails docs (though this is Rails 4) - http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit

Comment: This allows a user to set a new password shorter than 6 characters. I would instead validate "length" and "presence" separately (with [`validates_length_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_length_of) and [`validates_presence_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_presence_of)) so that the `on: :create` only confines presence validation.