# How to update password attribute with has_secure_password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bcrypt-ruby

I used `has_secure_password` for the `User` model. Now I am trying to use AJAX to update some of the user's attributes, including password. However, it looks like with `has_secure_password`, the `password` attribute no longer exists, replaced by `password_digest`. So when I am trying to do

```
user[:password] = "The password passed by AJAX"
user.save!
```

I got:

> ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (can't write unknown attribute
>   `password`)

The question is: What is the right way to update a user's password in this situation? Do I need to manually compute the hash and update the `password_digest`?

EDIT:

I am using Rails 4.2.1

Comment: Which rails version you are using ?

Comment: This may help for rails4 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475333/rails-update-attributes-using-has-secure-password

Comment: @PardeepDhingra thanks for the link, but it didn't quite help...My problem is about how to actually change the password field, not "not change it"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you just use:

```
user = User.find 1
user.password = 'Test123456789'
user.save
```

But, it sounds like you have not added a password_digest column to the users table or have not run the migrations.

Comment: Yep, I don't have a password column, since the has_secure_password authenticates using the password_digest column. I think not having password column is the intended way to use has_secure_password

Comment: I should have said password_digest. Corrected.

Comment: It's just this simple! But the `password_confirmation` must be set too. This is a bit inconsistent with how other columns can be changed. But at least this works.

Comment: It doesn't actually. I have never needed to do so and just tested it again.

Comment: OK. hmm I tested without, and got `Password confirmation doesn't match Password`. I used `user.save!`

Comment: Which is a completely different error than you specified in your original question.